# How to handle a click event of a child view of a listview item view?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, listviewitem

So..I want to create a list view whose views will be handled by a custom array adapter. Each view of this list view has a child text view. What I want to do is that I want to handle(launch an intent) the click event of this text view which is positioned within the view present within the list view. How do I do that? Would my suggested code run?

Suggested Code:

```
@Override
public view getView(int position, View convertView, View parent)
{
View v = convertView;
/*code…*/

TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_field);

t.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener({
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(thisActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
mp.start();
}));

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In order to help you answer your question, please provide further details.  What research have you done into the Android docs?  What code have you tried to implement on your own so far, and what errors (if any) have you encountered that prompted you to post a question here?

Comment: Did you tried the above(Suggested Code) code? what is the output?

Comment: @Mad code Yes, I did try to run this code...well sort of.Instead of playing audio on the click of the text view within the view, I wanted to play the audio upon the click of the view itself. It wasn't working initially and I kept tweaking it. I tried different versions of this code but none of them worked.My app wouldn't crash but it wont do my bidding as well(play the audio)

Comment: @RichieThomas I have enrolled on a course on Udacity for Android. During the course I have been made familiar with the Android Docs. For my original problem(a variant of the above problem), I had to finally implement onItemClickListener interface to handle my touch event, as was guided by my course instructor and the official docs

Comment: @PurusharthVerma did implementing `onItemClickListener` solve your problem?  If so, consider posting an answer to your own question below, including the specific implementation you used which resolved your issue.  This will help future site users who have your same problem to unblock themselves.

Comment: @RichieThomas onItemClickListener solved my original problem,It wouldn't solve my present problem though

Answer (score 1):

Just refer the below example.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (view != null) {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        } else {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder.storeName.setText(mShoppingLists.get(position).getName());
        holder.editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final FragmentManager manager = ((Activity) mContext).getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                ShoppingListEditFragment shoppingListEditFragment =
                        ShoppingListEditFragment.newInstance(mShoppingLists.get(position).getId());
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, shoppingListEditFragment, "shoppinglistedit");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        holder.handle.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                ((DynamicListView) parent).onHandleLongClickListener(new DragEvent());
                return true;
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my question to provide my code. Please help me out on that, I am a beginner and I am finding your code a bit troublesome to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle the click event of a listview item, here is the code for it:

```
    /*Inside the onCreate method of your activity class which displays the list
    ......*/
        ListView l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, 0, list, R.color.category_numbers);
        l.setAdapter(adapter);
        l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener({
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long 
        id) {
        /*your code*/
        }
    });
```

Comment: This sets click listener on whole list itemview, check my answer to set click listener on child elements of listitem view (if that is what you wanted).

Comment: Your @Override onItemClick function is as a parameter of function OnItemClickListener.. Wrong placed

Answer (score 0):

To capture click event on a child element inside a listview item, you also need to set `focusable="false"`on child element and `focusable="true"`on Listview itself.

Other than that, the code looks correct. So try setting `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` params.